# How to remove header from particular single page

Tags: wordpress

I'm a newbie at WordPress and php.
I want to remove the header from one or two pages only.
I saw this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-remove-footer-from-individual-pages

so I did this in my header.php file found under my theme folder

```
     <?php if( !is_page('18') ) :?> <!-- this is what I added -->
     <header class="banner">
     ...rest of html...
     </header>
     <?php endif;?>   <!-- this is what I added -->
```

Just for the sake of seeing if changes to this file were taking effect I also did `<?php if( false ) :?>` which was supposed to remove it from all pages but this didn't work either.

Though I don't know the difference, I saw some different syntax and so also tried  `<?php if(false) { ?>` and `<?php } ?>`

I am wondering if I have to do something else to have the changes take effect.

In case it matters, I am using the roots starter theme http://roots.io/starter-theme/
and WordPress 3.9.1

Comment: did you make changes in wp-content/roots-starter/header.php (I mean the right theme folder?)

Comment: @Trishul, I triple checked. How I wish it had been some simple oversight as this :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be editing the file `/roots/templates/header-top-navbar.php`. This get decided at [`base.php`](https://github.com/roots/roots/blob/master/base.php#L11):

```
if (current_theme_supports('bootstrap-top-navbar')) {
    get_template_part('templates/header-top-navbar');
} else {
    get_template_part('templates/header');
}
```

Just in case, add your code to both. I tested your code with `header-top-navbar.php` and works ok.

Comment: I believe what you mentioned would have affected all pages so I did it slightly different. I gave credit to answer because it ultimately led me to answer. So I have a template for each of my pages under my roots theme. For example template-find-page.php. Also roots theme has `base.php` file. I created another file,specifically to match up with my page template,and called it base-template-find-page.php. Copied over everything from `base.php` and comment out code dealing with showing header which is what brosofilo mentioned.So all other templates will still be using the base.php except this one.

Answer (score 0):

you are giving wrong condition it should be if(is_page('18'))
{// do nothing } else {...rest of html...}

Comment: Didn't see how this would make a difference but tried it anyway, and still no change.